# Echo in AIX Shell behaves weird or any reason behind it

Tags: shell, echo, aix

Here's a code in which i am trying to read a file having "*" in every line

File name : **test_new1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
op=new_file.txt
echo $op
while read line
do
name=$line
echo $name
done < definition.txt
```

My file contains :

```
this is the file * having various chars
```

the output of the above script is :

```
this is the file definition.txt test_new1.sh having various chars
```

i know the solution to the same . If i change `echo $name` to `echo "$name"` . It works fine .

But i would like to know why does echo behave this way .

**why does it list the files in my directory when not enclosed in double quotes** ?

my current O.S. is **AIX**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `*` gets expanded as all files in your current directory.

You can avoid it with two ways:

- As you said, by quoting, which makes shell interpret it as a string and not a parameter:

  ```
  while read line
  do
    name=$line
    echo "$name"            <---- echo within quotes
  done < definition.txt
  ```
- Deactivating `noglob`: [How do I disable pathname expansion in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/41013/143251).

  ```
  $ echo *
  one_file one_dir whatever

  $ set -o noglob              <--- disable
  $ echo *
  *

  $ set +o noglob              <--- enable again
  $ echo *
  one_file one_dir whatever
  ```

---

Quoting from `man bash`:

> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
>
> - Matches any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is enabled, and * is used in a pathname
>     expansion context, two adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match
>     all files and zero or more directories and  subdirectories.  If
>     followed by a /, two adjacent *s will match only directories and
>     subdirectories.